# Change Oracle APEX Search Placeholder Text

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I can't seem to figure out why, but my APEX page is showing "APEX.IG.SEARCH" as the search placeholder. How can I change this? I've looked through all of their docs and haven't found anything pointing to a fix.

If I have to, I can use JavaScript to change it, but wanted to see if there's an easier fix first. Also, on 5.0.4 of APEX

[image: Apex placeholder text]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is about *translating (Apex) messages" (https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-18.2/HTMDB/translating-messages.htm#HTMDB14004). Search that page for `APEX.IG.SEARCH`; you'll find it under the Interactive Grid Messages Requiring Translation section (which is quite long).

So, what to do about it and how to change it?

- while in App Builder, open your application
- navigate to its **shared components**
- in there, go to the **Globalization** section and click **Text messages**
- click "Create text message" and set

  - Name: APEX.IG.SEARCH
  - Language: leave it *as is* (English, probably)
  - Used in JavaScript: leave it *as is* (Yes)
  - Text: put your own message in here; for example, "Enter search criteria and push the GO button"
- Apply changes

If you run the page now, you should see the new text in the Interactive Grid Search's field.